# class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, mysql-connector

Currently i am using **liquibase -> 4.3.2** and **mysql -> 8.0.22** for my spring boot project. I am trying to create table through liquibase. It gets excuted first time . It creates 2 database by default . 1. **databasechangelog** and 2. **databasechangeloglock** . But when i try to run again then it gives me following error :

```
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.time.LocalDateTime and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')**
```

**Code for my db.changelog-1.0.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

        <changeSet id="1" author="auth1">
            <sql>
                CREATE TABLE user (
                id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                fname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                lname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                number BIGINT NOT NULL,
                password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
                );
            </sql>
            <rollback>
                DROP TABLE user;
            </rollback>
        </changeSet>
    
        <changeSet id="2" author="auth1">
            <sql>
                CREATE TABLE plant (
                plantname VARCHAR(50)
                )

            </sql>
            <rollback>
                DROP TABLE plant;
            </rollback>
        </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**code for db.changelog-master.xml :**

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"></include>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**application properties**

```
spring.application.name = Cleandrop-Backend


spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cleandrop?useUnicode=true&userLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

serverTimeZone=user-defined-time-zone
```

**I also tried to change mysql version still same. How can i solve this?**

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the `ClassCastException`?

Comment: Could you try and check with some different version of liquibase once? It seems to be some issue with liquibase, but I'm not sure about the version in which this issue is seen. Need to check that. Meanwhile try with some other version of Liquibase once.

Comment: @RakhiAgrawal Actually i checked earlier .. Some post with same type of issue , the problem is in mysql version , liquibase is fine according to post

Comment: oh is it? Thanks for sharing the details. Then maybe you can try changing mysql version if it helps.

Comment: I was also facing same issue. Changing liquibase version to 4.3.1 helped me resolve it. Reference: [here] (https://forum.liquibase.org/t/liquibaseexception-java-lang-classcastexception-class-java-time-localdatetime-cannot-be-cast-to-class-java-lang-string/5059)

Answer (score 12):

User `mohiitg` commented that changing to liquibase version **4.3.1** resolved the issue.

As of 2021-05-03, version **4.3.5** was available. Updating to this version solved the error for me.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/4.3.5

Answer (score 1):

It's just a versioning issue between liquibase and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when i used spring boot v: 2.4.0
try using  Spring boot version 2.3.0.RELEASE or earlier

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the version if you are testing locally just **delete** the tables created with databasechangelog,databasechangeloglock and then try with this cmd
liquibase --url=" " --changeLogFile=" "  --classpath="mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar" --username=root --password=root update  it will update successfully